# MySQL JOIN using more than one column and table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 3 tables that I need to JOIN, but I'm having difficulty getting the right result because I need information from more than 1 column. I wish to get all users that are available and has the status = 1. In addition, get both types 1 and 3. With users listed as type 3, I need to join with the other table (by user id) to get only users with a specific specialty listed on the other table.

My tables are similar to these:

```
users
id | status | availability | type 
1  | 1      | 1            | 1
2  | 1      | 0            | 1
3  | 0      | 0            | 2
4  | 1      | 1            | 3
5  | 1      | 1            | 3


specialties
id | type 
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 43
```

My relation table would look like this:

```
rel_users_specialties
id | id_user | id_specialty
1  | 1       | 29
2  | 2       | 3
3  | 4       | 3
4  | 5       | 3
```

My query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
JOIN rel_users_specialties r ON r.id_user = u.id
WHERE u.status = 1 
AND u.disponibilidade = 1
AND r.id_specialty = 3 
AND (u.type = 3 OR u.type = 1)
```

My expected result would be the following users (by id)
1, 4 and 5 (exclude user number 2 because of the availability = 0) and Although the user 1 has a specialty different than 3 it also has a type 1 (type one here would be a constant, regardless of the specialty selected).
Appreciate the help!

Comment: Why User 5 should come into result when it has the id_specialty as 4 not 3.

Comment: My bad! Will edit. Thanks

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: My problem is I need to get a combination of result based on the tables and columns as shown. So my question is how do I get users with status and availability = 1, type = 1 or 3, and (if type = 3) I need a know if user specialty is = 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the conditions like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u INNER JOIN rel_users_specialties r 
ON r.id_user = u.id
WHERE u.status = 1 AND u.availability = 1 
  AND ((u.type = 1) OR (u.type = 3 AND r.id_specialty = 3))
```

Or without a join:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u 
WHERE u.status = 1 AND u.availability = 1 
  AND (
    (u.type = 1) 
    OR 
    (u.type = 3 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM rel_users_specialties r WHERE r.id_user = u.id AND r.id_specialty = 3))
  )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ecdbfdd1f7828be155ce22683fc9a22e).

Comment: Thank you for the reply @forpas! Although it is working on fiddle, when I place it on my database I'm only getting users with type 3. The status and availability is working. On your second example it's return a mysql error.

Comment: @ArtFranco If your actual data is like the sample data you posted in your question then both queries in my answer would work as expected (there are no syntactical errors as you can see in the demo). So it seems that your data is different or you are not using my queries correctly.

Comment: I've only changed the table names and simplified it. But the construction is the same. Beside the fact that it is working and the logical aspect is sound, when using on my db it only select the type = 3, not joining with the specialty table. My expectation is to get all users type 1 and if there are type = 3, get the users with specialties = 3 (as in our example).

Comment: @ArtFranco I only know the sample data that you posted. Create a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7 with your actual data so I can test.

Comment: Thank you @forpas! I'll keep trying based on what you've sent.

Comment: Your answer worked! I just had to change for LEFT JOIN instead. Thanks a lot!